# Is "tight and bold" an English idiom?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I came across a paragraph  in “[Good Fit for Today’s Little Screens: Short Stories](http://www.nytimes.com/2013/02/16/books/a-good-fit-for-small-screens-short-stories-are-selling.html?src=me&ref=general)” in New York Times.

> “The generation of writers out of college in the last few years has been raised to engage with words like no generation before,” he said. “Our generation was raised on passive media like television and telephones; this generation has been engaged in writing to each other in text messages on a 24-hour basis. I think it has made them bolder and tighter.”

I don't know what "tighter" means here. Is "bold and tight" an idiom? what does it mean?

Answer (score 2):

> [ODO on *tight*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tight):
>
> **2** (of a rope, fabric, or surface) stretched so as to leave no slack; not loose:
>       • (of a written work or form) concise, condensed, or well structured:
>           *a tight argument*
>
> [ODO on *bold*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bold):
>
> **1** confident and courageous

Using text messages with their limited content and constrictive format has made this generation's written work concise and condensed without superfluity, and confident and courageous enough to write in that way.

Comment: ie 'bolder' and 'tighter' are separate modifiers, unlike 'spic and span'. Notice that 'tighter' must be considered a transposed epithet (it's the writing that's tighter) or wrong.